# Mongoose - TypeError: object is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am trying to export a Mongoose model from my `model/user.model.js` file to my `server.js` file, in my server directory.

**model/user.model.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema();

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    instagramId: { type: String, index: true },
    email: { type: String, unique: true, lowercase: true },
    password: { type: String, select: false },
    userName: String,
    fullName: String,
    picture: String,
    accessToken: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema, 'users');
```

**server.js**

```
var User = require('./models/user.model');

mongoose.connect(config.db);
```

I get this error message

> \server\models\user.model.js 5
>
> var UserSchema = new Schema({
>
> TypeError: object is not a function

I know I declared my schema as `UserSchema`, however I thought I exported the file with the variable `User`

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema, 'users');
```

I'm trying to use the name User to query my mongoose model.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are mistakenly assigning `Schema` to an instance:

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema();
```

Instead, it should be assigned the `mongoose.Schema` class itself:

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
```

Comment: @Raz time to post a new question then :)

Comment: Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52698337/mongoose-model-typeerror-schema-is-not-a-constructor