# Mongoose model TypeError: Schema is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have seen this question:
[mongoose TypeError: Schema is not a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40280783/mongoose-typeerror-schema-is-not-a-constructor)

However I still cannot using Models with Mongoose.

When I am trying this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose').connect(`mongodb://${process.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_PASSWORD}@localhost:27017/${process.env.DB_NAME}`, {useNewUrlParser: true});
  const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

  var blogSchema = new Schema({
    title:  String,
    author: String,
    body:   String,
    comments: [{ body: String, date: Date }],
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    hidden: Boolean,
    meta: {
      votes: Number,
      favs:  Number
    }
  });

  var Blog = mongoose.model('Blog', blogSchema);
```

I receive the following error:

```
TypeError: Schema is not a constructor
    at module.exports (/Users/razbuchnik/Projects/taxi4you/server/resources/permissions/api/v1-update.js:30:20)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/razbuchnik/Projects/taxi4you/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/razbuchnik/Projects/taxi4you/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at /Users/razbuchnik/Projects/taxi4you/server/app/middlewares/permission.js:27:7
    at /Users/razbuchnik/Projects/taxi4you/server/node_modules/mongojs/lib/collection.js:50:5
    at runInAsyncScope (/Users/razbuchnik/Projects/taxi4you/server/node_modules/mongojs/lib/cursor.js:198:5)
    at /Users/razbuchnik/Projects/taxi4you/server/node_modules/mongojs/lib/cursor.js:205:5
    at handleCallback (/Users/razbuchnik/Projects/taxi4you/server/node_modules/mongojs/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:120:56)
    at /Users/razbuchnik/Projects/taxi4you/server/node_modules/mongojs/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor.js:683:5
    at handleCallback (/Users/razbuchnik/Projects/taxi4you/server/node_modules/mongojs/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:171:5)
    at nextFunction (/Users/razbuchnik/Projects/taxi4you/server/node_modules/mongojs/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:691:5)
    at /Users/razbuchnik/Projects/taxi4you/server/node_modules/mongojs/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:602:7
    at queryCallback (/Users/razbuchnik/Projects/taxi4you/server/node_modules/mongojs/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:232:18)
    at /Users/razbuchnik/Projects/taxi4you/server/node_modules/mongojs/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:469:18
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

Note: this is a copy pase from official Mongoose site and GitHub repo.

Comment: try not to mongoose.connect, put connect to its own variable

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `mongoose` is not Mongoose object but [`connect` promise](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#mongoose_Mongoose-connect).

It should be:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.connect(`mongodb://${process.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_PASSWORD}@localhost:27017/${process.env.DB_NAME}`, {useNewUrlParser: true});
```

Notice that `mongoose.connect` may be suitable not for model but parent module because there could be multiple model modules.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone else has the problem and is still unable to figure it out, maybe in your model file instead of `module.exports=` maybe you have `module.export=`

This might not help op, but was something that caused me 30 minutes of pain, hence pasting it here.

Answer (score 1):

The error is because your `const mongoose` has the instance of `mongoose.connect` and not `mongoose`.

Try this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const connect = mongoose.connect(`mongodb://${process.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_PASSWORD}@localhost:27017/${process.env.DB_NAME}`, {useNewUrlParser: true});
  const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
  var blogSchema = new Schema({
    title:  String,
    author: String,
    body:   String,
    comments: [{ body: String, date: Date }],
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    hidden: Boolean,
    meta: {
      votes: Number,
      favs:  Number
    }
  });

  var Blog = mongoose.model('Blog', blogSchema);
```

Hope, this helps you.